# How to return a sorted list with multiple sorts and groupings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Given a list() with ko mapped objects with the following fields:
object

> name
>   status (on, off or idle)

I'm able to return the list grouped by status and then alphabetized as follows:

```
this.list().sort(function (a, b) {

    if (a.status() == b.status()) {
        return a.name().toLowerCase() < b.name().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
        return a.status() > b.status() ? -1 : 1;
    }

});
```

Problem is when a statu is set to idle, it is making 3 groups when I only want to status groupings at all times for on or off, ignoring any other status var.

Can this be made to only group statuses by ON & OFF and ignore all other status() variables like idle?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you would want to treat idle as "on" and then do the sorting/grouping that you had been doing:

```
  this.list().sort(function (a, b) {
      var aStatus = a.status() !== "idle" ? a.status() : "on",
          bStatus = b.status() !== "idle" ? b.status() : "on"
      if (aStatus == bStatus) {
          return a.name().toLowerCase() < b.name().toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1;
      } else {
          return aStatus > bStatus ? 1 : -1; 
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks RPN, but that no longer groups by status == 'on' and status() == 'off'. I would like to group by those two statuses only, ignoring the others and then alphabetized in those groups by name(). Thoughts?

Comment: Also I still want to include items that have a status() of idle, I would want that to be in the status ON group. Possible?